# Custom Build Activity to Label Branches after a successful build on TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I am new to Custombuild activities and I was looking for a way to change the label on a branch after a build is successful, I was reading up on System.Activities namespace. Can anybody guide me in the right direction. I just want to add a label according to the version of the build to my branch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Build by default automatically creates labels for you with the build number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I wasn't sure the range of this label. Thanks.